# JSON schema enum to C# class equivalent

Tags: c#, json, class, enums, schema

I have a JSON schema that I am trying to make a C# class out of.

The question I have lies quickly at the first property of the RootObject.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "version": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [ "3.0" ]
        },
        "vectorString": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [ "version" ]
}
```

vectorString is a string so that's easy:

```
public class RootObject {
    public string vectorString { get; set; }
}
```

However, version is a string AND has an enum modifier. My question is, how do I model static enum values in JSON schema to the C# class?

Comment: I am not sure at all what you mean by "enum modifier", but `version` is an object with a `string type` and `List<string> enum`. Try using http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I've tried and it's flawed. For example, to make an attribute required just add [Required()] above the class attribute, but json2csharp.com creates a class where the RootObject has an attribute that is an array called required.
So I follow your first statement that version is a string. So it looks like the vectorString attribute for the class. But where does enum come into play? Is that just telling us the data will be a string and it will only ever be a value in this enum (which is 3.0)

Comment: Use https://app.quicktype.io it has the converter to C#. But note that your enum field has "3.0" value that cannot be a valid enum value in C#, so some tricks are required to implement it and the mentioned converted does it. But you might consider a simple approach - just treat "version" field as a string. It depends on your desired usage scenario. You may even define a string const MyVersion="3.0" if you want to compare this field in your code instead of enum.

Comment: @SergeyL Correct. I can always set the property to a string and just do validation in my code to make sure the value is one in the "enum" the schema specifies. I just didn't know if there was a way to make the class mirror the schema information of the attribute being enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out I didn't need to worry about the enum metatag. just making a string property for version worked fine.